# How to add external javascript file dependency for Cordova javascript plugin?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webpack, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm going to create Cordova plugin on javascript which will use some external javascript dependencies. As I understood, all external js files must be сopied into www folder like this

```
<asset src="lib/restful.js" target="www/lib/restful.js" />
```

but what should I do next? How to register it as modules to make it accessable from Cordova plugin javascript code like this?

```
var restful = require('restful');
```

What is the best practise of usage external javascript libraries from Cordova javascript plugin code?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to bundle my dependencies with webpage but always get runtime errors.